# How to initialize a variable which won't be refreshed

Tags: python, scripting, animation-nodes

I am coding a node for animation nodes. I need to initialize a set of variables so I can use them, but I need to do it in such a way that they won't be refreshed (reset to the default value) every time I send an output to the node.

I probably want to define the variables before my `create(self)` method, so it won't refresh every time I send/receive I/O from the `execute(self,a,b,...)` method.

I have this:

[image]    def create(self)
       new.Input(...)
       new.Input(...)
       new.Output(...)
       etc...

```
def execute(self,a,b,etc..)
   loops involving variables.
```

Where do I define my variables, and what is the syntax for calling them to check or change values without resetting them to their default start settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define such variable outside of the node class and call it as you would call a global variable. Take the *Text File Reader* node for example, it defines a cache dictionary to cache file reads, the cache is initially defined outside of the class as:

```
cache = {}

class TextFileReaderNode(bpy.types.Node, AnimationNode):
    bl_idname = "an_TextFileReaderNode"
    bl_label = "Text File Reader"
    ...
```

And it assign and read the cache in the execute function normally:

```
with open(path, "r", encoding = encoding) as f:
    data = f.read()
    cache[key] = (lastModification, data)
    ...
```

You can also use the node identifier as a key in the dictionary to have a per-node variables. For instance, if you want a variable `xBounce` for every node, create an empty dictionary called `xBounce` and in the execution function, set its value using `xBounce[self.identifier] = something` and retrieve its value using `xBounce.get(self.identifier, 0)` where zero is the default value

Comment: I tried declaring three integer variables before the node itself, as you have shown here, but I still get a referenced before assignment error.  I don't know how to show my code here in the comments, or I would add that to this question."  Can you suggest what is going wrong?

Comment: @NullNaught Please add the code to the question.

Comment: When I try to copy and paste, I get "866 characters too long."  I don't know how to append my screenshot.  I will try adding it as an edit to my question.

Comment: @NullNaught It seems Python assumes the variable is in the local scope. You should probably declare it as a global variable, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function).

Comment: Can you tell me, is there any way to achieve the same thing without a global variable? I can't use two such nodes at the same time, when I would like to be able to.

Comment: @NullNaught If you want a per-node variable, create a dictionary and use the node identifier as its key. You can get the identifier using `self.identifier`. Does that make sense?

Comment: I will investigate this answer, is there an answer that demonstrates this use?

Comment: @NullNaught I edited my answer to explain how to use this method.